# How can you update prices on previous orders?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I put a Magento (1.9.2.4) site live for a week and took around 30 orders, which I can view in reports.  Unfortunately, I had to revert to the client's previous site when some issues came up.

I now need to provide the client with accurate sales and profit margin reports for the 7 days I had the site up.  The problem is, some of the product pricing (for the wholesale/cost figures) wasn't correct at the time so the reports I produce don't have the correct figures for margin and profit.

Is there any way I can force Magento to use the current (and correct) product pricing rather than some of the incorrect product pricing at the time the transactions went through?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Why dont you try to update the order with latest pricing.